# Difference between 'sale agreement' and 'agreement for sale'

Tags: usage

Can we use the term "sale agreement" so as to denote an "agreement for sale"?

An "agreement for sale" is in essentially a contract to sell a property in future.

Comment: Use where and how? In a legal document? As a program variable? In casual conversation? At a seminar?

Comment: Mainly in a legal document, but like to know whether both can be interchangeably used in a formal seminar too.

Comment: That would have been better edited into your question, rather than put in a comment below it.

Comment: Legal documents frequently use arcane or uncommon language for very specific legal reasons, I wouldn't rely on normal English rules of usage in that context. For example, you're more likely to hear "sale**s** agreement" in normal use, but a legal agreement might use different technical language for other reasons.

Comment: As @BradC said. Usage in legal documents should be advised by a legal professional.

Answer (score 1):

Standard terms in U.S. business practice are a **sales agreement** and an **agreement of sale**, with both meaning a formal contract for one party to sell and the other to buy. You can look both terms up on a search engine and find lots of references. Under the Statute of Frauds, certain contracts of sale must be formalized in writing to be enforceable. The huge majority of sales, however, occur without any written contract. For example, purchases at a supermarket involve no written contract.

The terms that you references, **sale agreement** and **agreement for sale**, are not standard phrases in business practice in Pennsylvania.

Answer (score 0):

An 'agreement for sale' is the condition one has to accept before he/she buys or sale. While 'sale agreement' in most cases appears in form of document to claim the ownership of a particular property.

Comment: This is correct, also note the plural in "**sales** agreement", which differs from the question. This is more commonly used.

Comment: This answer may be correct, but should be properly sourced with examples and references, especially since this deals with *legal language* that may not be familiar to many native speakers.  Please add those and I'm happy to change my vote.